# Video making tool with api to combine pictures and music into a video

Tags: linux, api, video

Is there a video making tool on linux that has an api which I can use to combine pictures and music into a video?
I just found youtube editor. I can add multiple pictures and make a video. Unfortunately it doesn't have an api. Is there anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a video slideshow from images](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

```sh
# each image will have a duration of 5 seconds
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i img%03d.png -i music.m4a -r 30 out.mp4
```